# What is the best (free) upload/sync Flickr plugin to for iPhoto?

Tags: macos, sync, iphoto, upload, flickr

I'm looking for a iPhoto plugin that would allow me to easily upload photos from iPhoto to my Flickr Pro account. Ideally such a plugin would allow you to:

- Uploaded selected photos only in their full size.
- Manage Flicker sets.
- Just work and give no hassle.

Advice is welcome for both free an reasonably priced plugins.

Thanks!

Boaz

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc. It's safe to assume OSX. iPhoto does not have a Windows version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [FlickrExport](http://connectedflow.com/flickrexport/)?

> **Features:**
>
> FlickrExport for iPhoto provides a comprehensive set of features for getting your images from iPhoto to Flickr:
>
> - Edit photo titles and descriptions, and add tags to them.
> - Save time – FlickrExport can update iPhoto's database with the titles and descriptions you give your photos.
> - Save your Flickr bandwidth allowance – FlickrExport for iPhoto can resize your photos before uploading.
> - Create a new photoset with your photos, or add them to an existing photoset.
> - Automatically send your photos to a Group Pool on Flickr.
> - Choose from a list of your Flickr tags and add them to your photos before uploading.

[image: FlickrExport]